# Does Blazor support .Net Core or .Net 5.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor

Does Blazor support .Net Core or .Net 5.0? When I create a new project with the templates available in VS2019 I get a .Net Standard Blazor project in my solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: The client-side Blazor projects target .NET Standard 2.1. That is correct. They will run using the runtime compiled to WebAssembly.

Comment: Hmmm, that is sad. The shared code library we use is .Net Core 3.1. That doesn't mix.

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET **Core** 5. If you want to use a library with multiple runtimes, even multiple *Core* runtimes. And Blazor Wasm *does* support .NET 5. I use it since RC0 for reporting dashboards, but my shared libraries are all .NET 5 or .NET Standard 2.1 (those I haven't changed to .NET 5 yet)

Comment: @PaulSinnema It’s unlikely that you have something in your .NET Core 3.1 library that isn’t also supported on .NET Standard 2.1. Have you tried switching the target?

Comment: No, not yet. Our development team would like all new projects to be .Net Core if possible.

Comment: Do you realize what .NET Standard is? Library project should default to .NET Standard unless you actually have a need to target a specific newer runtime.

Comment: I must honestly say I'm bit lost in all the different .Net tastes. So why should it default to .Net Standard?

Comment: [.NET Standard](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard) is the set of APIs that runtimes support. By sticking to .NET Standard, you are allowing for the most compatibility across different runtimes.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work for me. One of the NuGet packages in that library does not support netstandard.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, Blazor has a .Net 5 version with numerous improvements: https://www.codemag.com/Article/2010102/Blazor-Updates-in-.NET-5

Depending on your version of VS however, you might need the preview branch to use it.

Comment: By now it's RTM. I've been using .NET 5 with Blazor WASM for months

Comment: Ah, that's nice to hear. I tried setting the target to .Net 5.0. It does compile but at runtime I get an error. Could not find the assembly 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll' referenced for the in-process application. Please confirm the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is referenced in your application.